# Библиотека js по изменению форм в SVG элементах

Tags: svg, path, svg-animation

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите кто знает аналог библиотеки https://greensock.com/morphSVG только бесплатный. Необходимо менять path форму у SVG элемента с одной на другую посредствам JS

Comment: Она более-менее [бесплатная](https://greensock.com/standard-license)...

Comment: У меня есть собственный скрипт, который изменяет path d. https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/ws4xknot/

Comment: @Yuri красиво работает, но на SVG код был бы в несколько раз короче.

Comment: @Alexandr_T, не спорю :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде всего разработка Дмитрия Барановского (Dmitry Baranovskiy) [snapsvg.io](http://snapsvg.io/)

К сожалению он закрыл поддержку своей другой, более ранней библиотеки [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Вот интересный пример, как с помощью snapsvg делать, то, что вы хотите - [Elastic SVG Elements](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/12/15/elastic-svg-elements/)

Вспомнил, что на гитхабе осталась поддержка [Raphaël](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/).

Разработка Олега Соломки [mojs](http://mojs.io/) - появилась недавно, но активно используется судя по  количеству примеров на codepen.

Пример [там же](https://tympanus.net/Development/Animocons/).

[Velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/) и ещё есть достаточно много библиотек для трансформации SVG.

**UPD** 19.01.2017

[15 JavaScript-библиотек для анимации SVG](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_2429.html)

Можно делать трансформацию фигур вручную, поверьте это не сложно. Главное условие, чтобы количество точек во всех подпутях - M0,50 L50,0 L100,50 совпадало по количеству.

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">

      <title> The path line</title>
    <desc> The path line http://svg-art.ru  </desc>
  
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="grey" fill="greenyellow" />
  <path d="M0,50 L50,0 L100,50" stroke="dodgerblue" fill="dodgerblue" >
       <animate  dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"
     attributeName="d"
    values="M0,50 L50,0 L100,50;
            M0,50 L50,100 L100,50;
      M0,50 L50,0 L100,50;"/>
        </path>     
 </svg>
```