# SVG анимация изменения формы

Tags: анимация, form, svg, css-animation

Добрый день уважаемые. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не получается перевести из одной формы SVG в другую? Вот пример

```html
<svg class="keyhole" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="minKeyhole" fill="red" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="1" d="M50.3,50.1l-0.1-0.7c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.2
 c0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0,0,0,0,0l-0.2,0.7L50.3,50.1L50.3,50.1z"
 />
<animate xlink:href="#minKeyhole" dur="5s"

 repeatCount="indefinite"
attributeName="d"
values="
 M50.3,50.1l-0.1-0.7c0.1,0,0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.2c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.2
 c0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1,0.2c0,0,0,0,0,0l-0.2,0.7L50.3,50.1L50.3,50.1z;

 M67.5,82.9l-8.8-39.7c3.9-2.7,6.5-7.2,6.5-12.2c0-8.2-6.6-14.9-14.9-14.9S35.5,22.8,35.5,31
 c0,4.6,2.1,8.6,5.3,11.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.6,1.2,0.9l-9.4,39.7H67.5z"
 keyTimes="0;1"
/>

</svg>
```

Почему оно не пересчитывает переходы, а просто лупит ключевые кадры? Как поправить, что б не было этого рывка, а был плавный переход ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Библиотека js по изменению форм в SVG элементах](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616315/%d0%91%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-js-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc-%d0%b2-svg-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо морфинг патча и масштабирование в одном флаконе не работают. Может и ошибаюсь, надо исследовать этот вопрос. По крайне мере у меня тоже не получилось. Когда масштаб не изменяется всё работает. Пример ниже.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="keyhole" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 250 250" id="svg2" width="250" height="250" style="border:1px solid blue;">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="dodgerblue" />
  <path id="minKeyhole" d="M 100 200 C 100 100 200 100 200 100" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="3">
   <animate  dur="5s" begin="0.1s"  repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="d"
values="M 100 200 C 100 100 200 100 200 100; 
M 100 100 C 80 150 200 100 150 250;
M 200 200 C -80 350 50 20 100 50;
M 150 100 C 80 150 350 100 150 50;
M 100 200 C 100 100 200 100 200 100"  />
  
  </path>
</svg>
```

Можно применить анимацию увеличения масштаба - `scale`, но координаты фигуры будут пересчитываться и увеличение будет совмещаться с движением фигуры, что видимо вас тоже не устроит.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="keyhole" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" id="svg2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid dodgerblue;">
  
  <path id="minKeyhole" fill="red" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"  d="M67.5,82.9l-8.8-39.7c3.9-2.7,6.5-7.2,6.5-12.2c0-8.2-6.6-14.9-14.9-14.9S35.5,22.8,35.5,31
 c0,4.6,2.1,8.6,5.3,11.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.6,1.2,0.9l-9.4,39.7H67.5z">
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
      type="scale" values="1;11"
      additive="sum" begin="0s" dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
       
  </path>
</svg>
```

Интересный вариант с использованием анимации `viewBox`. Тут можно и одновременно увеличивать масштаб за счет уменьшения координат `viewBox` и 
удерживать фигуру в центре за счет изменения атрибутов `viewBox` - `min-x` и `min-y` Подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=5) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615562/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9-viewport-%D0%B8-viewbox).

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="keyhole" version="1.1" viewBox="-550 -550 1200 1200" id="svg2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid red;">
  
  <path id="minKeyhole" fill="red" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"    d="M67.5,82.9l-8.8-39.7c3.9-2.7,6.5-7.2,6.5-12.2c0-8.2-6.6-14.9-14.9-14.9S35.5,22.8,35.5,31
c0,4.6,2.1,8.6,5.3,11.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.6,1.2,0.9l-9.4,39.7H67.5z" />
  
  <animate  attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "0s" dur = "10s" values = "-550 -550 1200 1200;-25 -25 150 150;-550 -550 1200 1200" 
  fill = "freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</svg>
```

Еще один пример. Добавил паттерн.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="keyhole" version="1.1" viewBox="-550 -550 1200 1200" id="svg2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <defs>
      <pattern id="newpattern"
             x="0" y="0" width="80" height="80"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <g fill="#85D2FF"  fill-opacity="0.7">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
             <rect x="40" y="40" width="40" height="40" />
            </g>
      </pattern>
              
  </defs> 
  <rect x="-550" y="-550" width="100%" height="100%"
         style=" fill: url(#newpattern);" /> 
  <path id="minKeyhole" fill="red" stroke-width="1" stroke="black"    d="M67.5,82.9l-8.8-39.7c3.9-2.7,6.5-7.2,6.5-12.2c0-8.2-6.6-14.9-14.9-14.9S35.5,22.8,35.5,31
 c0,4.6,2.1,8.6,5.3,11.4c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.6,1.2,0.9l-9.4,39.7H67.5z" />
   
  <animate  attributeName = "viewBox" begin = "0s" dur = "10s" values = "-550 -550 1200 1200;-25 -25 150 150;-550 -550 1200 1200" 
  fill = "freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Огромное, спасибо, за столь развернутый комментарий по теме.  К большему сожалению я прочитал что современные браузеры постепенно отказываются от SMIL анимации                                    SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.asp Из-за чего пришлось лепить средствами CSS http://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/MJmQJv Я правда так и не понял почему у меня на codepen появляется "мусорный" бардюр вокруг моей svg работы.(с идентификатором #drawer)

Comment: Слухи о скорой кончине SMIL SVG сильно преувеличены. Год уже как этот вопрос обсуждается в сообществе гугловского хрома. Все там восстали против убирания анимации. И хром отложил на неопределенное время. Разработчики хрома мотивировали своё желание убрать анимацию тем, что дескать мало используется в вебе SMIL Поэтому всем нам, кто любит анимацию SVG нужно больше её применять. Моё твердое убеждение, что на SVG можно легко делать оч. интересные вещи. https://svg-art.ru/files/animation/viewBox-translate/viewBox-translate2.html